# How to measure .net app memory usage without allocating memory?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, memory

I'm working with a performance-sensitive WPF application, and want to log out some key memory usage stats for my application every second. My overall aim to to avoid the penalty of garbage collection as much as possible, by ensuring that my app doesn't allocate (much) memory as it's running.

There's plenty of information around about how to get this information, either through performance counters, or VirtualMemorySize64 on the current process.

My problem is, the VS2013 profiler tells me that these calls themselves are causing a significant amount of memory allocation.

Just getting the RawValue of a "Private Bytes" performance counter causes the allocation of nearly 3MB in a couple of seconds, and another nearly 3MB is allocated for calls to VirtualMemorySize64.

Is there a more performant way to get these numbers?

Comment: Run other process for collect stat information.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, seems heavyweight though. Why don't you recreate that comment as an answer in case it ends up being the best idea, and so that others can comment?

Answer (score 0):

Run other process for collect stat information.

```
    public static void CollectStatInfo(int pid)
    {
        var memorySize = Process.GetProcessById(pid).PrivateMemorySize64;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        switch (args.FirstOrDefault())
        {
            case "--collect-stat-info":
                var pid = int.Parse(args.ElementAtOrDefault(1));
                CollectStatInfo(pid);
                return;
        }

        CollectStatInfoFromOtherProcess();

        //code
    }
    public static void CollectStatInfoFromOtherProcess()
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                Arguments = $"--collect-stat-info {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}",
                FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: This shows how to let an executable start itself with a command line argument. That does not answer the question _"How to profile my app's memory usage"_ at all.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is answer to question "How to profile my app's memory usage without measure measuring code"

Comment: No, you added a lot of code that just starts another instance of the current process, passing the PID of the old instance. Before the edit, that was all it does; now it calls `PrivateMemorySize64` which OP mentions has problems. This is most certainly not something you'd want to do every second.

Comment: @CodeCaster Problem exist when `PrivateMemorySize64`called in current process and no problem when `PrivateMemorySize64` called in other process.

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea if you started up the Monitoring process when the subject application starts, and use inter-process communication to ask it to take measurements. Still feels heavyweight.

Answer (score -1):

Why don´t you utilize:

```
 My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory
 My.Computer.Info.AvailableVirtualMemory
 My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory
 My.Computer.Info.TotalVirtualMemory
```

These functions does not require any memory expense.

I guess you don´t need to monitor, so granularly, your memory (like Private Bytes, Working Set, etc.) and Garbage Collect may help you to control that usage in a good way.

Comment: I'm trying to monitor the memory usage of my own application, whereas those stats are for the computer as a whole.

Comment: I guess you can get them in the first line of LOAD event and save them to see how the application is going on. The main problem is not how memory your program allocates at startup, but how much it allocates during its execution - and using them your code/time/execution penalties will be the lower as possible. Other methods can show granularity but consumes more CPU, memory and sometimes require Admin priviledges.

Comment: This is worse than useless, it could easily give false results if something else is happening on the machine (e.g. a virus scan)

Comment: You´re right, of course. But anyway, if you have any other process consuming memory, you won´t be able to perform actions. I mean, I understood your problem is related to available/free memory for your application, not exactly how much memory it´s consuming in particular. In my applications I´m worried about how much global free memory I have before perform some heavy-consuming routines. Anyway, sorry if I couldn´t helped you.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and if that was my goal, it would be a reasonable way to achieve it. However I'm trying to make sure that my app is allocating as little memory as possibly while in its steady-state, because I want to avoid the penalty of garbage collection as much as possible. I'll update my question to make that more clear.